# Splide.js is not working in tabs (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, tabs, slider, bootstrap-vue

I am using splide.js. The options I set for the slider do not work under the tabs of bootstrap vue.

Comment: Please provide some more information and show what your code looks like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.